# Sequelize migration & seeder issue. ERROR: Unable to resolve the storage: It can also be referred to for how we can setup password protected sqlite

Tags: sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

I am getting `ERROR: Unable to resolve the storage:` when running sequelize seeder. Although I was able to run migrations (to create, update tables).

Following is my config file

```
module.exports = {
development: {
dialect: 'sqlite',
storage: 'path-to-db',
seederStorage: 'path-to-db',
password: 'some-private-key-to-make-db-password-protected',
dialectModulePath: '@journeyapps/sqlcipher',
dialectOptions: {
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
  },
},
},
staging: { .. //and so on
production: { .. //and so on
```

[image: Error screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue what I was doing wrong.
Notice
storage: 'path-to-db',
We need to pass 'sequelize here

```
    storage: 'sequelize'
```

Will work like a charm